# How to have structs and pointers of a class as a type so you can pass them to functions?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, struct

I am trying to write a library in Qt and it contains three C++ classes. `clsA` which should be single instance per application (that is why I have `Instance` function). `clsA` instantiate number of `clsB` depend on different states which it should keep the pointers to interact with it them later. `clsC` is an interface which should be implement by the developer later on and get instantiated and the pointers of them should be passed to `clsA::init` function. So if a developer wants to use the library he/she should write something like this:

```
QList<clsC*> l;
clsC1* one = new clsC1();
l.append(one);
clsC2* two = new clsC2();
l.append(two);
//and so on

clsA* a = clsA::Instance();
a->init(l);
```

And the class `clsA` looks like this:

```
#include "clsB.h"
#include "clsC.h"
namespace MRZ{
namespace Core{

class clsA :public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
       static clsA* Instance()
                   { if(instance == NULL) return new clsAlertManager(); }

       //stores the pointers in a Qmap
       void init(QList<clsC*> _listOfPointers); //line number 37

protected:
       static inline  clsC* getclsCPointer(QString _key) //line number 42
                   { return clsCPointers.value(_key);}

private:
       static clsAlertManager* instance;
       clsAlertManager(){instance = this;}

    // depend on some variables this method instantiates clsB and store
    // the pointers in another QMAP called clsBPointers with some int ID
       void initclsB(); 

      QMap<int, clsB*> clsBPointers;
      QMap<QString, clsC*> clsCPointers;
 };
 }
 }
```

And nothing special about class `clsB` header except I have declared a struct in it like this:

```
 namespace MRZ{
 namespace Core{

 struct myStruct { int Value; };

 class clsB: public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
     //calss definition

};

}
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MRZ::Core::myStruct)
```

and also in one of `clsB` function:

```
 bool clsB::someFun(Qstring _key)
 {
   clsC* c = clsA::getclsCPointer(_key);
   return c->someOtherFun(myInstantiatedStruct);
 }
```

And `clsC` which is the interface that should be developed later in the application looks like:

```
 namespace MRZ{
 namespace Core{

 class clsC
 {

 public:
    clsC();

    bool someOtherFun(struct myStruct _struct);//line number 39
    { return this->isTure(_struct.Value);}


 protected:
    virtual bool isTrue(int _value) = 0;
    //some virtual function that should be developed later
};

}
}
```

But when I try to build the project I get lots of error indicating:

```
clsC.h:39: error: '_struct' has incomplete type
clsC.h:39: error: forward declaration of 'MRZ::Core::myStruct'

clsA.h:37: error: 'clsC' was not declared in this scope
clsA.h:37: error: template argument 1 is invalid

clsA.h:42: error: 'clsC' does not name a type
```

I have included the header files just fine, and this is the part of the "simplified version" of the part of the code that generates errors. And I have been searching the internet and read some where that I may need to write a wrapper function to instanciate the pointers before hand for me, but I didn't really get the concept. Any comment or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you included the `clsB` header in `clsC`?

Comment: yes it seems like clsB is not included in clsC. Maybe clsC is also included from some other header in your code? I would suggest to put ` `#include "clsB.h"`  in clsC.h and use `#ifndef` to ensure that it is loaded only once

Comment: yes I have them include with `#ifndef` but still I get the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a struct by value (that is, not as a reference, const reference or a pointer to it), the contents of the struct must be known to the code using the struct - and of course, when using member variables of the struct, the exact contents of the struct MUST be known. In other words, `clsC`'s code must contain a definition of `struct myStruct` to allow the compiler to generate the code that fetches `value`.

In your case, that may well mean that `struct myStruct` needs to be declared in a different headerfile.

You have some other errors that are completely unrelated, and I'm pretty sure they are not even in the code you posted, which makes decoding them a bit difficult.